# Prove log(log(n)) is Big-O (log(n))

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity

I need to show that:

$g(n) = \log(\log(n))= O(\log(n))$

This is what I have so far:

Choose $k = 1$

Suppose $n > 1$ then:

$\log(n)  <  n$

$\log(\log(n)) <  \log(n)$

But I can't figure out what my `C` should be if this is the correct answer?

Comment: $C=1$ works fine.

Answer (score -1):

If $0<f(n)<g(n)$ then $c=1$ works to show $f(n)=O(g(n))$.